# How can i drop this session cookie and whats wrong here?

Tags: c#, cookies

this is my code:
http://pastebin.com/y0VHgRNs

Okay Basically, What i need to do is make the system check for a username on every second line here. If that username is there.. it would vote with that username. But the problem is.. it stops at the first request which is when line3 != null
And.. 'im guessing it needs to log out as well.. How could i possibly drop the cookie container and create a new one or could i just go to a logout.php script?

Hope that's informative enough, if not leave a comment.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it stops at the first request", do you get an error?

Comment: Runs this one: http://pastebin.com/r6S52Kmv But then doesnt run the one after that which is if line3 != Null and it is not Null so.. No errors btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's because you're doing a `while(loopvar < 7)` but you're not resetting the value of `loopvar` before you do another `while`.

The first `while` will loop until `loopvar` is 7, but when your try and do another `while`, `loopvar` is already 7, so it won't run.

Add this line just before each `while(loopvar < 7)`

```
loopvar = 1;
```